# Precompile Assets Failed Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, precompile

I'm deploying Rails 4.0.1 on Heroku however when I try to precompile I get the following error:

```
$ rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant SampleApp
c:/Sites/sampleapp/config/initializers/secret_token.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
c:/Sites/sampleapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is my environment.rb:

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Sampleapp::Application.initialize!
```

The line in secret_token where it finds a problem:

```
SampleApp::Application.config.secret_key_base = secure_token
```

And this is my application.rb:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module Sampleapp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

Comment: Heroku will precompile your assets for you.  You do not need to do this locally first.

Comment: On another note, I see a mixture of cases for your app name: sometimes I see SampleApp and sometimes I see Sampleapp.  If you get those aligned it will help your situation.

Comment: Thanks! I just needed to change the secret_token (SampleApp to Sampleapp). However I didn't understand why it also found an error on environment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `application.rb`, your project uses `Sampleapp` as its name. As such, ensure that all your core files utilize the identical name – *including capitalization* – in your option configuration:

```
# config/initializers/secret_token.rb
Sampleapp::Application.config.secret_key_base = secure_token
```